# Any reason not to bend the pins on TQFP and VQFP packages

Tags: fpga, pins, tqfp

I have an FPGA with a VQFP package, and I need to bend some pins back and hand solder them to fine gauge wire. Is it likely that this will damage the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply bending a pin up won't damage the chip. It's a common technique for troubleshooting and repairing a board with a layout error.

However, those pins are extremely small and will break off very easily. Be gentle and don't bend it up and down more than one or twice. It'll snap right off.

I try to find a narrow, sharp instrument (a sharp pick or the edge of a razorblade), heat the pad with the solder iron, and use the instrument to carefully lift the pin straight up. Once you have the jumper wire soldered to the lifted pin, you can support it by dropping a glob of hot glue over the whole area.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to make sure I wouldn't damage the thing. I'll be careful not to break the pins off as well